# VBA: Extract specific word table to excel

Tags: excel, vba

Edited: SO I managed to identify all th word docs. However, I'm having a problem achieving to extract the 2nd column row 2 data of the table.

Error: Set Table = doc.Table
Object variable block

The word table looks like the attached img. I only wanted to extract the "x" starting from row 2 column 2..

Hoping someone can actually help me on this.. Thank you in Advance!

[image]

```
Sub Open_Multiple_Word_Files(sPattern As String)
Dim shApp As Object
Dim shFolder As Object
Dim File, Files
Dim currentPath As String
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim wd As New Word.Application
Dim sh As Worksheet


'get folder
    Set shApp = CreateObject("shell.application")
    folder2search = "C:\Users\ChrisLacs\Desktop\extrac\"
    Set shFolder = shApp.Namespace(folder2search)
'get files
    Set Files = shFolder.Items()
'check if file names match the pattern
    For Each File In Files
        If File.Name Like sPattern Then
        
        
           

Set Table = doc.Table
Set sh = ActiveSheet

lr = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

For i = 1 To 6
    sh.Cells(lr, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Table(1).Rows(i).Cells(2).Range.Text)
    
            
            Debug.Print File.Name & " - " & (File.Name Like sPattern)
            Next
        End If
    Next File
End Sub

Sub Search_it()
    Open_Multiple_Word_Files "Form*"
End Sub
```

Comment: You have to enumerate the files matching your pattern in a folder. Google finds thousands of tips how to do that in VBA. Please try some out and come back if there is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only opens a single word file, because this line:
`Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Form.docx")`
only opens the specifit file that you say so.

One way to open all word files in a specific folder that match the pattern `Form*` is the following:

```
Sub Open_Multiple_Word_Files(sPattern As String)
Dim shApp As Object
Dim shFolder As Object
Dim File, Files
Dim currentPath As String
'get folder
    Set shApp = CreateObject("shell.application")
    folder2search = "C:\Users\...\Documents"
    Set shFolder = shApp.Namespace(folder2search)
'get files
    Set Files = shFolder.Items()
'check if file names match the pattern
    For Each File In Files
        If File.Name Like sPattern Then
            'write here things to do when pattern s matched.
            'Debug.Print File.Name & " - " & (File.Name Like sPattern)
        End If
    Next File
End Sub

Sub Search_it()
    Open_Multiple_Word_Files "Form*"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. First, thanks for the modification. Just one question will it address to extract just the second row column 2 table?